# Python: .pop() on unordered sets

Tags: python, set

I have a question regarding the .pop() method. In the documentation, it states that on sets:

> Remove and return an arbitrary element from the set.

So what exactly does "arbitrary" mean? Like, for example: If I wanted to build a queue from a list of users where position is determined at random, could I enter in all users into a set, and then build a randomly assigned queue using .pop()?

So the code would look something like

```
queue_set = {'bob','rachel','sara','david'}
queue = dequeue([])
while queue_set:
        queue.append(queue_set.pop())
```

Would that be a reasonable way to randomly assign members to an index? Or is the .pop() reliant on some way the data is entered or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

"Arbitrary" means the implementation returns whichever element is most convenient.  You are not guaranteed randomness.  Use `random.sample()` or `random.shuffle()` if you need random selection.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way would be to use `random.shuffle`

```
>>> import random
>>> li = ["bob", "rachel", "sara", "david"]
>>> random.shuffle(li)
>>> li
['sara', 'bob', 'david', 'rachel']
```

If you want to get the elements one by one, you can then use `li.pop()`.